# Different type of MEAN Stack Architectures

Tags: architecture, javascript, api, node.js, angularjs

I am reading a book (**Getting MEAN by Simon Holmes**) about MEAN Stack which talks about different architectures that can be used while developing an app in MEAN Stack and I got a little confused with that.

**First I'll tell you how I develop applications in MEAN:**

- My Front-End is a templating engine like EJS or Jade.
- I render pages through my Node/Express.js Server.
- I also use AngularJS on the front-end, I have angularJS controllers to manage the scope and functionalities of different features in the app and I use Angular Services to communicate with my Node.js Server and make HTTP calls to my routes.
- I create a Node.js Server using Express.JS and then create a REST API.
- I create API routes using Express.js
- I use MongoDB for database and mongoose for database connections etc

The above described architecture is the one I use but the book I am reading talked about a few more and I am confused about how they are setup and work.

**The 3 different architectures described in the book are:**

- A Node.js and Express Application
- A Node.js and Express Application with AngularJS additions for interactivity
- An AngularJS SPA (Single Page Application)

Heres the image representation of the 3 architecture in the book:

[image]

**Can anyone explain how these 3 approaches are different from what I do and how they are setup?**

Comment: The difference between the three architectures is the technology that is chosen for the front-end.  No, really.  You've already stated the reason for the existence of three different frontend architectures in your question.  If you want a more specific answer than this, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

MEAN stands for MongoDB, Express, Angular and Node, which gives us the following:

- The top using only Node, Express and MongoDB isn't a MEAN application because it doesn't use Angular.
- The middle is a MEAN app since it uses all technologies, but its different from the last one as it uses Angular features but not single page application, SPA.
- The bottom one is also a MEAN app, and it uses SPA, which contains the whole application in one page, as opposed to the middle one which have more than one page.

I would say you are using the middle one in your architecture, since its perfectly alright to add on other techniques in a MEAN app.